Token information in the IPFS appears with a delay?
I have a question: I'm using Helius RPC and they send me data on my webhook, so after TOKEN_MINT (token creation) I immediately receive token data, and get metadata (with link on IPFS).
After that, when I got IPFS link I'm trying to get token info (like description, social networks, etc) using .get request on IPFS.
The main problem is that IPFS returns None (but after some time it returns all token infos). So, how quickly does information appear in the IPFS? And how can I speed-up retrieve of this infos?
Use-Case code:
# After webhook data received
response = requests.get(url=token_metadata["data"]["uri"])  # IPFS
data = response.json()
>>> None


You may need to ask your question somewhere else, I don't know if any IPFS experts are checking this site unfortunately
